# Can't access localhost via public IP

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I'm having trouble enabling public access to my XAMMP setup. I've been looking at a few threads over at Tom's Hardware forums to resolve this issue but can't figure out were I'm going wrong. Whenever I enter the public IP address I keep getting my router's login page when I enter my public IP into the browser on my PC or mob (which is on the carrier's 3G network)

I have a Belkin router port forwarding, httpd.conf and vhost per below - am I missing something?

```
Belkin - Port forwarding
inbound:80
type: TCP
internal private pc: 10.1.1.2
private port: 8181

-----------
httpd.conf
Listen 8181

-----------
httpd-vhosts.conf

NameVirtualHost *:8181

## Events Demo
<VirtualHost *:8181>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@eventsdemo.localhost
    DocumentRoot "L:/xampp/htdocs/eventsdemo.localhost"
    ServerName eventsdemo.localhost
    ServerAlias eventsdemo.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/eventsdemo.localhost.log"
    CustomLog "logs/eventsdemo.localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Quite obviously not a programming question. Voting to move.

Comment: #1 - Make sure your router is configured to *not* serve its configuration interface to the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern routers have an option to put their management on your public IP address so that they can be for some reason or another managed remotely off the private LAN.

When this feature is enabled the routers web interface will be binding it's self to your public IP address and port 80. 99% of the time this will actually take precedence over any port forwarding that you have setup on the router.

Once you disable this remote management your website should be live.

Finally another thing to remember is always check from another PC/Internet connection if you can't find anything wrong with the configuration. I have seen a number of routers display management interfaces when the public IP is entered from on the private LAN, even if the port forwarding works externally.

See the below screen capture for an example of what you need to disable:

[image]

Comment: Hi iTom, remote management unchecked, port 80 forwarding to 8080 , checked "fixed" IP for my PC in the DHCP page , accessing from LAN goes straight to router still, outside of LAN i get a error "Connection reset by peer"?